# Parse a list of lists in configuration file in python

Tags: python, config

I can read a configuration file with a list like this:

```
# config file is called config.txt
[PARAMETER]
site_loc      = [45.77,-87.20]

# Read in site_loc list
import  ast
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

# Parse config file
parser = SafeConfigParser()

parser.read('config.txt')
```

Is there a way to read a list of lists? e.g. `site_loc = [[45.77,-87.20], [23.0,-45.0]]`

Comment: I can't get your example to work... It's giving me an empty list when I do `parser.read('config.txt')`. Also, I think that function wants a file, not a string...

Comment: I had to do `parser.read(open('config.txt','r'))` to get the empty list. Otherwise it gave me `['config.txt']`

Comment: rofls, you need to create the config.txt file. The data in config.txt is site_loc...

Comment: I did create it... :)

Comment: `>>> t=open('config.txt','r')
>>> for i in t:
...   print i
... 
[PARAMETER]

site_loc      = [45.77,-87.20]
`

Comment: I am using python2.7 64 bit, maybe you have a different version?

Comment: Nope, I have that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex config files like yours, it's probably better to use a third party configuration library. For example:

https://github.com/toml-lang/toml

https://github.com/avakar/pytoml